# How to fake a click on an NSTextField?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I have an NSTextField. I'd like to programmatically invoke a mouse click on it. Is this possible?

I know I can just make the field a first responder, but I'd just like to know if a fake click can be used to achieve the same effect.

Comment: What is your actual objective here: to give focus to the text field? To insert the cursor in a particular spot?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want, you can make your own [mouse event](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/mouseEventWithType%3alocation%3amodifierFlags%3atimestamp%3awindowNumber%3acontext%3aeventNumber%3aclickCount%3apressure%3a) and then pass it into [`-[NSApplication sendEvent:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/sendEvent%3a).

But, really. Just use [`-[NSWindow makeFirstResponder:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/makeFirstResponder%3a).